# The day PyCharm thought int / float does not implement __div__

Tags: python, pycharm

**UPDATE**
This issue is solved in PyCharm 2017.2

```
def foo(x):
    return x / (60 * 60)

z = 1
y = 2
bar = 0 if y == 0 else z / y

foo(bar)
```

This causes PyCharm 2017.1.4 with pretty much default analyzer settings (I believe) show the following warning:

> Expected type `'{__div__}'`, got 'Union[int, float]' instead.
>
> This inspection detects type errors in function call expressions. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases

Now, of course Python doesn't have static type checking, but it is obvious here that `bar` will always be `int` or `float` (and PyCharm understands it as evident by `got Union[int, float]` in the above warning).

So, is this a bug in PyCharm with this specific use case in which it fails to see that `int` and `float` do implement `__div__`, or is there something else that I'm missing here?

**UPDATE**

Oddly enough, if `foo` is modified to `return x * 60 * 60` the warning goes away and PyCharm doesn't warn about `x` not implementing `__mul__`.

**UPDATE 2**

Changing `foo` to `return float(x) / (60 * 60)` obviously makes the warning disappear, but `x` is already inferred as `int` or `float` as evident by the warning itself.

Definitely seems like a bug in PyCharm.

Comment: Version **2016.2.3** works fine and so does **2017.1.3**.

Comment: How about `return x / 60 / 60`?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug of your PyCharm Version, I can't reproduce it in 2017.1.2

Edit: Which Python compiler do you use? 2.7x or 3.x?

Comment: PyCharm 2017.1.4 and Python 3.4.2

Comment: Try `return (x / (60 * 60))` or forcing it to be float `return float(x / (60 * 60))`

Comment: Still the same warning. However `return float(x) / (60 * 60)` makes the warning disappear but this is trivial, and shouldn't be necessary since PyCharm already infers `x` to be `int` or `float`.

Comment: Well then just see it as an useless warning. You could just ignore it, since apparently PyCharm/Python does the thing that you want anyways. And if that warning bothers you too much, you know how to get rid of it.

Comment: True, I'll try to reproduce this error after I hit home from work on another PyCharm Version I have, this time with Python 3.x

Comment: Even with PyCharm 2017.1.4 and Python 3.x I cant reproduce your problem (OS Linux Mint 18)